# HRESULT Value for Skipping File(s) in IFileOperationProgressSink::PreCopyItem method

Tags: winapi, com

I am trying to find a way to skip one or more files in a `IFileOperation::CopyItem` method where an entire folder is copied to a new destination.

The way I am attempting this (Plan A) is by testing for the file(s) in the `FileOperationProgressSink::PreCopyItem` method and, if there is a match, return a value such as `COPYENGINE_E_USER_CANCELLED (0x80270000)`. Otherwise, return `S_OK`. Unfortunately passing `COPYENGINE_E_USER_CANCELLED` has the effect of cancelling the **entire operation**, not just the copy operation of the current file. Plan B would be to enumerate the files to be copied and test the files(s) before performing a copy operation but it seems cumbersome.

If Plan A seems feasible, I would appreciate it if you could share the `HRESULT` value that would allow me to skip the current file. The fact that the system copy function includes the option to skip one or more files in the event of a collision suggests that there is a way to do so but I am not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: The `PreCopyItem` documentation clearly states: "*Returns S_OK if successful, **or an error value otherwise**. In the case of an error value, the copy operation **and all subsequent operations pending** from the call to IFileOperation are canceled.*"  That doesn't leave any room for skipping just the current file.  I think you will have to resort to your Plan B to iterate the files beforehand and decide which ones should be copied or not.

Comment: As Remy said, when the `PreCopyItem` function returns an error, the copy operation will be canceled. But if you can use the [`IFileOperation :: SetOperationFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-setoperationflags) function to set the way to handle the file, it can achieve a pop-up dialog to skip when conflicts The function of one or more files.

Comment: Though not part of the official contract you could try to return `S_FALSE` and see if that has the desired effect. `S_FALSE` is a *success* code commonly used to convey that an operation didn't run to completion, yet not due to a genuine error (e.g. [IEnumVARIANT::Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-ienumvariant-next)).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thank you for reminding me to carefully read the **Return value** section of the documentation. As you said, the language doesn't leave room for anything but either a successful pre-copy or an error, which affects all subsequent operations. Plan B seems to be the only way to skip files. @Zhu Song - Thank you for your suggestion. I am aware of the `IFileOperation::SetOperationFlags` method but it doesn't achieve what I am trying to accomplish. @IInspectable - Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to return `S_FALSE` but it didn't work. It looks like the official contract is tight.